# Refresh data without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a function for adding likes on the page

**blade.php**

```
<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}?type=heart" class="comments-sub-header__item like-button">
<div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count">
  {{ $article->like_heart }}
</div>

<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}?type=finger" class="comments-sub-header__item like-button">
<div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count">
  {{ $article->like_finger }}
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
  });

  $('.like-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
      url: href,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function() {
        window.location.reload();
      },
    });
  });
});
```

But when I click on the like to update the data, I reload the page using `window.location.reload();`

Can this somehow be done without reloading the page?

This is how adding likes is implemented, they are added to cookies and stored for 24 hours

web routes

```
Route::post('article/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@postLike');
```

Article controller

```
public function postLike($id, Request $request) {
        $article = Article::find($id);

        if(!$article){
            return abort(404);
        }

        $type = $request->input('type');
      
        if ($article->hasLikedToday($type)) {
            return response()
                ->json([
                    'message' => 'You have already liked the Article '.$article->id.' with '.$type.'.',
                ]);
        }
    
        $cookie = $article->setLikeCookie($type);
      
        $article->increment("like_{$type}");
    
        return response()
            ->json([
                'message' => 'Liked the Article '.$article->id.' with '.$type.'.',
                'cookie_json' => $cookie->getValue(),
            ])
            ->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

Article model

```
public function hasLikedToday(string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        if (!array_key_exists($this->id, $articleLikes)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($type, $articleLikes[$this->id])) {
            return false;
        }

        $likeDatetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $articleLikes[$this->id][$type]);

        return ! $likeDatetime->addDay()->lt(now());
    }

    public function setLikeCookie(string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = Cookie::get('article_likes', '[]');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        $articleLikes[$this->id][$type] = now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $articleLikesJson = json_encode($articleLikes);

        return cookie()->forever('article_likes', $articleLikesJson);
    }
```

Comment: just add a class to color the like button from ajax success method. You can also return the number of likes from the POST response and update the data in the markup from the success method.

Comment: @TaimurSaeed I am not good at ajax and js, and I do not quite understand how to do this, so I ask for a more detailed answer

Comment: please be descriptive then what kind of data you want to update on ajax success

Comment: @TaimurSaeed everything in the php.blade that I added to the post, with the `comments-sub-header__item-icon-count` class

Comment: @TaimurSaeed `{{ $article->like_heart }}` and `{{ $article->like_finger }}`

Comment: Hello again, could you please show your controller?

Comment: @OzanKurt Hi, added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those DIVs hold the number of hearts, if the response of the target page is the new number of hearts then:

```
 success: function(data) {
    targetElement.find(".comments-sub-header__item-icon-count").html(data)
 }
```

elsewhere if you want to add +1 to current number regardless of server response:

```
 success: function() {
    var current= parseInt(targetElement.find(".comments-sub-header__item-icon-count").html());
    targetElement.find(".comments-sub-header__item-icon-count").html(current+1)
 }
```

Footnote: as the ajax request is nested inside the click function, the **targetElement** in my codes is the clicked element. You may get it in defferent ways e.g.

```
$('.like-button').on('click', function(event) {
     var targetElement=$(this);
     ....
}
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens until I refresh the page

Comment: There should be some other error preventing the function to work properly. Please check the console to find where the error occures.@chu

Comment: there is no error, I checked everything, the data just doesn't update

Comment: Ok. I found that you put the ajax  request nested inside the click function. So I have updated the answer according to the `targetElement` I descried in foot notes.@chu

Comment: still nothing changes until I refresh the page

Comment: Oh my God! You have also nested the DIV inside the `<a>` elements (also forgot to close  `</a>`)  So I changed all .next() to .find() . It should work now! @chu

Comment: yes now everything works, thanks a lot)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
  });

  $('.like-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
      url: href,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        $(this).parent(".comments-sub-header__item-icon-count").html(
parseInt($(this).parent(".comments-sub-header__item-icon-count").html()) + 1
)
// or return like or heart count from server
$(this).parent(".comments-sub-header__item-icon-count").html(response)
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: tried it, nothing happens until I refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
$(function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
    },
  });

  $(".like-button").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const likeBtn = $(this);

    $.ajax({
      url: likeBtn.attr("href"),
      type: "POST",
      success: function () {
        let currentCount = likeBtn.next().text();
        likeBtn.next().text(parseInt(currentCount) + 1);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: get error `Uncaught ReferenceError: parsetInt is not defined`

Comment: sorry for typo its `parseInt`

Comment: there is no error, but nothing is updated without reloading the page

Comment: you can attach a debugger in the success method to see why this is happening. Its difficult to suggestion a solution without looking at a working solution

Comment: how can this be done?

Comment: using chrome devtools or adding `debugger` statement in the code

Comment: got something like that `success: ƒ success()
type: "POST"
url: "/article/41?type=finger"
xhr: ƒ ()
[[Prototype]]: Object
currentCount: ""`

Comment: this is if you put a debugger at the end of the function, if at the beginning then `currentCount: undefined`

Comment: Can you try `console.log` both `currentCount` and `likeBtn` and `likeBtn.next()` variables to check their content?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the new count to the response from your controller.

```
return response()
    ->json([
        'message' => 'Liked the Article '.$article->id.' with '.$type.'.',
        'cookie_json' => $cookie->getValue(),
        'new_count' => $article->{"like_{$type}"},
    ])
    ->withCookie($cookie);
```

Now you can use the updated count as `new_count` from the database.

```
$.ajax({
    url: href,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        $(this).next().text(response.new_count)
    },
});
```

Comment: unfortunately did not help( data is not updated without reboot